# sharepoint powershell - Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed:"

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

something is wrong and i don't know what's it ,the same script is working in my local machine but when i tried it in VM it just will not work and throw me exception

-the PowerShell is the same version 
-the same PowerShell SDK
-i added rule to allowing PowerShell 
-my user is admin
-all the parameters are correct and i can enter the SharePoint in browser

```
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Clear-Host
# getting all argument before starting the process #
$SiteURL = "user"
$ListName = "list"
$Username ="email"
$Password ="pass"

if ($SiteURL -eq $null -or $ListName -eq $null -or $Username -eq $null -or $Password -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Output "Somthing went wrong!"
        Write-Output "Some of the variables are not correct"
    }
else
    {
        $outfile = $PSCommandPath | Split-Path -Parent
        $outfile += '\items.txt'
        Clear-Host
        Write-Output "Getting Items"
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $securePassword=ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
        $Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $securePassword)
        $Web = $Context.Web
        $List = $Web.get_lists().getByTitle($ListName)
        $itemCreateInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
        $ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
        $Context.Load($ListItems)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        $ListItems | ForEach-Object {
            $output=$_["Title"] + "~~"
            $output | Out-File -FilePath $outfile -Append
        }
        Write-Output "Done!"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's seems the security for the local machine has a SSL Certificate for my account by default but in the VM it was missing that Certificate, so i just invoked by using TLS 1.2

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

to the first line of my power-shell code and everything worked nice

Answer (score 0):

Works fine based on my testing.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

Clear-Host
# getting all argument before starting the process #
$SiteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee"
$ListName = "testlist"
$Username ="user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password ="password"

if ($SiteURL -eq $null -or $ListName -eq $null -or $Username -eq $null -or $Password -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Output "Somthing went wrong!"
        Write-Output "Some of the variables are not correct"
    }
else
    {
        $outfile = $PSCommandPath | Split-Path -Parent
        $outfile += '\items.txt'
        Clear-Host
        Write-Output "Getting Items"
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $securePassword=ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
        $Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $securePassword)
        $Web = $Context.Web
        $List = $Web.get_lists().getByTitle($ListName)
        $itemCreateInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
        $ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
        $Context.Load($ListItems)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        $ListItems | ForEach-Object {
            $output=$_["Title"] + "~~"
            $output | Out-File -FilePath $outfile -Append
        }
        Write-Output "Done!"
    }
```

Comment: it's seems the the issue is not it the code it's in the VM machine, i will try to fix that if i can, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Yes I confirm, it works, I had the same problem on a Windows 2012 R2 server